# Why is the print statements not output before the error in the code using Python/Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have this function below. It creates a list of notes. No note in this particular list is matching the expression. The function should therefore pop up the message box (because in this case there is no notes to be found) and end the function with return. But instead it throws the except block code. And why is not the print statements that is before the error outputted? Is not the code read line by line?

```
def report(): 

    # function to click on the first occurrence of a report in the note list
    try: 
        global clicked # To create a global variable inside a function, you can use the global keyword.
        clicked = "false" # set default state to false

        notesList = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, relativeXpathNotes))) #creates list with 10 notes

        print(notesList)
        
        print("test before next button code")
        nextButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, xpathNextButton)))
        print("this is the element for next-button: ", nextButton)
        print("test after next button code")

        isEnabled = nextButton.is_enabled() # Check if element is actually clickable. This will return true if the button is clickable.
        print("Is the button clickable?: ", isEnabled)

        found = False # set default state to false

        patternForFindingNote = r"notes"
        
        # start the first for loop
        for note in notesList:
            match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
            if match:
                print("The note to be clicked is: ", note.text)
                note.click()
                found = True
                break

        print("test before popup")    
        if ((not found) and (not isEnabled)): # this is the code that I expect to trigger if no match/notes is found. if not found any notes and the next button is not clickable, then there is no more notes to be found.
            print("No more notes found in this first list of notes. You have signed all reports. Good work!")
            # pop up message box
            messagebox.showinfo("Good work!", "No more notes found. You have signed all reports.")
            return # you can use the return statement without any parameter to exit a function. Exit the function if no more weekly/monthly notes are found. 

        print("test after popup")   
        if(not found) and isEnabled: # if not found in the whole loop (after all iterations) and if the next button is truly clickable (i.e. there is more items on the next page) then click next button
            isClicked(xpathNextButton) # this function should click on the next button and then return clicked as True 

    except TimeoutException:
        print("Failed to load elementItem")

    # code to get the actual note type string from the match above, e.g. "report 2"
    global fullstring
    fullstring = match.group() 
    print("The fullstring from match.group() is: ", fullstring)
```

The output is:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="72d612d5-105c-4d96-b1b3-b43de7dcb02e")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="4811db69-329d-4153-beef-0a615163d29f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="bf376a4c-d38e-4f76-8e29-a6977849a1f3")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="cfb83654-9541-4c89-9430-a5179c5b7b57")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="0f20091b-6802-4bb2-b09f-aa7207e82bdd")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="de32e469-a305-4b95-bd77-71b5e249839e")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="673268e1-cf6c-4d42-b056-e1771766006f")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="df7b9e51-f321-49ca-a4a7-a5d4475741a9")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="79acc1ca-88e5-4c0f-8f01-045f1c16be99")>, <selenium.webdriver.firefox.webelement.FirefoxWebElement (session="e0a0b70e-7e2a-40ff-b688-f292877ba4b7", element="41ce3a7e-a8c7-4331-a1e5-d3bcaec25010")>]
test before next button code
Failed to load elementItem
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KAAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1884, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "W:\test.py", line 2813, in clicker1
    report()
  File "W:\test.py", line 279, in report
    fullstring = match.group()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'match' referenced before assignment
```

I have checked that the xpath for the next button is right. Why is not the print statements outputted, e.g. 'print("test after next button code")'? The code before this print statement should be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails here `fullstring = match.group()` because you use `match` before you create such reference BEFORE you're invoking `.group()` method.

Despite you're creating `match` here:

```py
for note in notesList:
    match = re.search(patternForFindingNote, note.text) #if match then click on the element/item
    if match:
        print("The note to be clicked is: ", note.text)
        note.click()
        found = True
        break
```

Your code does not reach this statement because your `wait` genrates the exception, hence the rest of the code is skipped.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it with this code `if match: #if there is no match, then match.group code won't work so assign fullstring only if there is a match.
        global fullstring
        fullstring = match.group() 
        print("The fullstring from match.group() is: ", fullstring)`